# Check and replace file same name only

Tags: windows-10, script, search, find-and-replace, move

Example:
 **Folder 1** has A to Z file name
 **Folder 2** has only V to Z file name

I want to move then replace file in **Folder 2** only with same name from file in **Folder 1**. is there a cmd/script...etc to do this?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We suppose you have only two folders (**`Folder 1`** and **`Folder 2`**).

In **`Folder 2`**, you have file names which are surely also in **`Folder 1`**.

You want to move (overwrite) from **`Folder 1`** to **`Folder 2`** only files with the same name; as a result in **`Folder 2`**, you will have the same number of files, while in **`Folder 1`** you will have fewer files because they had to be moved.

In CygWin you can do:

```bsh
find Folder2 -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf %f\\n | while IFS= read -r filename ; do mv "Folder1/$filename" "Folder2" ; done
```

For `cmd` you can do:

```powershell
for /f "delims=" %f in ('dir /b "Folder2"') do move /y "Folder1\%f" "Folder2"
```

Comment: thank you, will this only move and replace file with same name only from Folder 1 to Folder 2 or it will move and replace than add unmatch file name from folder 1 to folder 2>

Comment: i will try your cmd script, i will post later, take time im new to this kind of thing,

Comment: Test with cmd with some random file, work like charm!!!, can you make it clear "The system cannot find the file specified" log cmd output msg, cus in folder 1 i had 13,795 file 5.04 GB while in Folder 2 3,539 Files 1.12 GB i dont start run it yet worry cmd frezze or something happen

Comment: Thank you once again everything work fine

Comment: problem solved mark this as complete

Comment: "The system cannot find the file specified" could happen if you have in **Folder 2** files which are **not** in **Folder 1**. This is the reason why I specified that as an assumption in my answer.